# Can't do anything except move

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

For some strange reason, nobody on my Bukkit server can break or place blocks or use blocks (crafting table, furnace) without me turning them into an operator. I believe this to the the biggest glitch that minecraft could have. It is very annoying to the players and after speaking to a few people, I have come to the conclusion that it is most likely a permissions error. I use [PermissionsBukkit](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permbukkit/) as well as [Vault](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/vault/) and [WorldGuard](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/worldguard/). Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't mention if they tried to break blocks away from the spawn. Can they?

Comment: They cannot break any blocks, even in the nether.

Comment: If this is the case, then the problem is a plugin. As far as I know there is no vanilla option to disable building for all non-ops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How far are they from spawn?  It's likely [spawn protection](http://forums.multiplay.co.uk/minecraft/77835-spawn-protection).  To disable it, use `spawn-protection-size=0` to your server.properties file.

Comment: They are on spawn, and `spawn-protection` in Bukkit.yml is already set to 0 (there isn't one in server.properties). It gets annoying when I'm hosting a skyblock server.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Try disabling all the plugins and see if the problem persists, then re-enable them one at a time to figure out what the culprit is.  Figuring out which plugin is causing the problem is a good start to figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PermissionsBukkit, users cannot build unless the node `permissions.build` is set to `true`. Check out the PermissionsBukkit [configuration](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permbukkit/pages/configuration/) page for more info.

So, for example, to allow everyone to build by default (in your `plugins/PermissionsBukkit/permissions.yml`:

```
groups:
    default:
        permissions:
            permissions.build: true
```

If you only want one user to be able to build:

```
users:
    kuyan:
        permissions:
            permissions.example: true
```

You can also set a message that will be shown to the user if they attempt to build but don't have the correct permissions:

```
messages:
    build: '&cYou do not have permission to build here.'
```

Answer (score 1):

For this solution you have to use the plugin GroupManager.

Kind of found this by accident, but I use GroupManager and the way to solve it was to go into

> plugins->groupmanager->worlds->world->groups.

Open with notepad++ or similar, then find default group and it should say: `"build: false"` Change this line to `"build: true"`.

Comment: Why would OP use GroupManager? He already said that he was using PermissionsBukkit (the PermissionsBukkit equivalent is `permissions.build`).